# both /revisions methods are spotty

Tags: bug, status-completed

These are the urls for a couple of my valid endpoint tests of the /revisions methods.

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/revisions/2688191  (?key=xxx)
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/revisions/2350874/d6b99e8e-0f6c-4f68-92d0-6a050feea1fc?fromdate=1245345415&todate=1308417415   (?key=xxx)

These urls are valid but very often I recieve

```
{ "error": { "code": 500, "message": "A generic error has occurred on the server; developers have been notified." } }
```

If I retry immediately the same error is returned. If I wait a few minutes before retrying it seems to work fine. this happens more often with the first url (/revisions). in fact if you hit it and refresh a few times you are likely to get a repro.

It is as if the endpoint 'heats up and needs to cool down' or there is an undocumented, harsh and anonymous throttle being implemented (i doubt this).

ooooeeeeee, whassup up widat? whassup up widat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.